# "Send to Mobile" ends with API Error Code 191 and error message "redirect_uri is not allowed by the application for OAuth"

Tags: facebook-apps, facebook-app-center

The native iOS app is listed on Facebook App Center. But there is issue with "Send to Mobile" action, it fails with error:

> API Error Code: 191
>   API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
>   Error Message: redirect_uri is not allowed by the application for OAuth.

Because the app is configured as a native iOS app, there is no any domains and redirect URI entered.

P.S. I know there is plenty of questions about [API Error Code 191](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/search?q=api+error+code+191). But at the moment none of them was helpful, thus, I believe my question isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be a lot of different reasons for this error, but I had the same issue where clicking on the "Send to Mobile" resulted in error 191.  In my case I was able to fix it by adding FB page URLs to the "Valid OAuth redirect URIs:" field in Advanced Settings.

I added the URL for the app in the App Center, as well as my main FB page - careful to use the correct URL scheme (https):

https://www.facebook.com/MyFBPage

https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/myfbapp

Hope that helps.